# Toast not displaying on compose activity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, toast

so probably dumb question for someone with experience with Jetpack Compose, but for some reason my Toast are not displaying. Here's the snippet for it. I'm sending 3 toasts with `.show()` in different parts of the `onCreate` method, and still nothing happens. I also tried using `LocalContext.current` as context inside a `@Composable` function but same result, nothing is displayed. I see online many different examples, even videos on youtube in which this exact same could should run. Anybody knows why?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Toast.makeText(this, " ASDASDASD ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    setContent {
        Toast.makeText(this, " ASDASDASD ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        MyApplicationTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                Toast.makeText(this, " ASDASDASD ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Greeting("Android")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A sample code to show `Toast`.

```
setContent {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    MyAppTheme {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ) {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Show Toast")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me break down the important things to look into in this code.

1. `Toast` should not be part of the composable code, rather it should be part of the side effect code.
   (e.g. `onClick()`, `LaunchedEffect`, `DisposableEffect`, etc.)
2. Get the context inside the composable code using `LocalContext.current`. Note that you have to store it in a variable as the code inside `onClick()` does not have composable scope. (As mentioned above).
3. Composables recompose very frequently depending on the UI changes, we don't want to show a `Toast` every time the composable recomposes.

Refer to [Side Effects Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) to understand it better.

Comment: What happens when giving application context to makeText in onClick?  It seems leaking memory?

Comment: @LeoXJ, `LocalContext.current` returns the current composable context, not the application context.

Comment: That I know.  I had given application context to makeText in onClick.  LeakCanary seemed to complain about memory leaks, for which I don't understand.  With local context, it appears the complaints are gone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `scaffold` for displaying toasts

**Code:**

```
class SimpleFormActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
            var inputFieldState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                scaffoldState = scaffoldState
            ) { padding ->
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(50.dp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    TextField(
                        value = inputFieldState,
                        label = {
                            Text(text = "Enter your name")
                        },
                        onValueChange = {
                            inputFieldState = it
                        },
                        singleLine = true,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            scope.launch {
                                scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                                    inputFieldState,
                                    duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                                )
                            }
                        }) {
                        Text(text = "Click")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: But this is Snackbar, not Toast